# ios swift concatenating function results with another string

Tags: ios, swift

For multiline button text I believe you add "\n" to the string.  However I'm having trouble concatenating my function results and the newlinetext

setTitle:

```
HomeVC.getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid") + "\n newlinetext"
```

I need help getting my function results concatenated with "\n newlinetext"

Comment: What do you see as button text?

Comment: @neo this is the setTitle portion of my button text.  I need to concatenate the function results with another string

Comment: what does getFriendCount return, a String or an Int?

Comment: @asifmohd getFriendCount returns a string

Comment: @SlopTonio Please update your question with the exact error message and code that reproduces the issue. You currently haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify an error, so I'm not sure, but I'm betting `getFriendCount` returns a number.

Try this:

```
let count = HomeVC.getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid")
let title = "\(count)\n newlinetext"
```

Comment: This worked.  getFriendCount returns a number as a string

Answer (score 0):

I've already encountered this. There must be some problem with (string + string) because it just ignores \n, though I never understood why this is. You can fix it by using join function:

```
let stringsToJoin = [getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid"), "newlinetext"]
let nString = join("\n", stringsToJoin)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSString's [stringByAppendingString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:) method

```
let aString = NSString(string: HomeVC.getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid"))
let concatenatedString = aString.stringByAppendingString("\n newlinetext")
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of NSString, even though the solution will work for sure.. The reason is that it is swift, and why not use it - there are solution even in swift. But that is my personal preference

Comment: @JiriTrecak I did not know that join could work as well.
So yeah, your answer is much better.

Answer (score 0):

If your method

```
HomeVC.getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid")
```

returns and optional string, then you need to unwrap it before concatenating.

Try

```
HomeVC.getFriendCount("2",id:"friendid")! + "\n newlinetext"
```